# plsql nested table

Tags: plsql, nested

In my package specs I put:

```
type table_info is record (table_name varchar2(20), col_info c_info);
```

In the declaration zone of my body I have:

```
t_info table_info := table_info();
```

When I compile I get:

> Error: PLS-00222: no function with name 'TABLE_INFO' exists in this scope

What's the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize a variable of record type:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE typ_rec IS RECORD (a NUMBER, b NUMBER);
  3     rec typ_rec;
  4  BEGIN
  5     rec.a := 1;
  6     rec.b := 2;
  7     dbms_output.put_line(rec.a + rec.b);
  8  END;
  9  /

3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

If you're using nested table of records however, you need to initialize the collection:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE typ_rec IS RECORD (a NUMBER, b NUMBER);
  3     TYPE typ_tab IS TABLE OF typ_rec;
  4     tab typ_tab := typ_tab(); -- initialization
  5  BEGIN
  6     tab.extend;
  7     tab(1).a := 1;
  8     tab(1).b := 2;
  9     dbms_output.put_line(tab(1).a + tab(1).b);
 10  END;
 11  /

3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

You can mix record types and collection types (varrays don't need to be initialized):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE column_info IS RECORD(
  3        col_name  VARCHAR2(20),
  4        col_value VARCHAR2(1000)
  5     );
  6     TYPE c_info IS VARRAY(10) OF column_info;
  7     TYPE table_info IS RECORD(
  8        table_name VARCHAR2(20),
  9        col_info   c_info
 10     );
 11     l_table  table_info;
 12  BEGIN
 13     l_table.table_name := 'TABLE_NAME';
 14     l_table.col_info.extend;
 15     l_table.col_info(1).col_name := 'COL_NAME';
 16     l_table.col_info(1).col_value := 'COL_VALUE';
 17  END;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

For further reading: [PL/SQL collection documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHIEBJC)

Comment: As you can see , the second member of this strusture is a collection  type column_info is record                                        (col_name varchar2(20), col_value varchar2(1000));
type c_info is varray(10) of column_info; When I assign a value to col_value , like this : t_info.col_info(1).col_name:='table_idx';     I get ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding information in comments.